# Streamreader.Read blocks / RedirectStandardOutput used

Tags: c#, process

I am trying to use StreamReader to read output data from a process, but the StreamReader blocks and won't return any of the output.

My Process looks like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.Arguments = args;
startInfo.FileName = filename;
StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = aDirectory;
StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();
```

The StreamReader is called right afterwards:

```
StreamReader strmRead = p.StandardOutput;
char[] output = new char[4096];
while(true){
   strmRead.Read(output,0,output.Length);
   string outputString = new string(output);
   Debug.WriteLine(outputString);
}
```

The code hangs at the call to the Read method. When I manually kill the program the output from the process is written to the debug console. The process output does not use newline characters so using Process.OutputDataReceived does not work. How can I get the process output from the stream without having it block indefinitely?

**Edit:** Given the answers I've already gotten it seems like a problem with the process not giving up standard out or not flushing output rather than anything wrong with my code. If anyone else has any insight feel free to comment.

Comment: I edited the title of your question so it would better suggest your problem, maybe you'll get some more useful answers that way.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading 4096 bytes and there might be less, so stream blocks.

Also, there are more efficient ways of reading text from the streams.  `TextReader` have `ReadLine` method, try that instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readline.aspx

BTW, `while (true)` ???  How do you plan to exit?

Comment: +1 StreamReader also has ReadLine and ReadToEnd which may be useful.

Comment: There are no newline characters in the output so ReadLine will block also.

Comment: Also the program still blocks if I change the number of bytes to 4 instead of 4096.

Comment: Hm, did you try with some other process, maybe there's a difference in how the output is flushed?

Comment: Okay the code works fine with a different process. How could the output flushing be affecting it? When I do not redirect the output I can see it appear right away in the console window.

Comment: Well, that's something I can't really tell.  Different run-time libraries have different ways of dealing with console output.  Sorry.  I know that being able to read progress of the application is sometimes nice-to-have, but it's a hack anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
String outputString = strmRead.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: The exact same thing happens with ReadToEnd instead of Read.

Comment: Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx). It talks about deadlock conditions a couple of paragraphs down.

Comment: So you are saying that the process is never giving up standard out for the StreamReader to read from it?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. Looking back and forth between your code and the snippet at msdn, you appear to be doing basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old. But I had a similar problem. I tried using the Peek() method, but even when Peek() returned -1 it wasn't always the end of the stream.

I fixed my problem by **starting a new thread** which tried to read the next character when Peek() returned -1.

```
                    string toRead = "";
                    do
                    {
                        if (reader.Peek() == -1)
                        {
                            Thread td = new Thread(TryReading);
                            td.Start();
                            Thread.Sleep(400);
                            if (ReadSuccess == false)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    td.Abort();
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex) { }
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                toRead += ReadChar;
                                ReadSuccess = false;
                            } 
                        }
                        toRead += (char)reader.Read();
                    } while (true);
```

TryReading() method is defined here:

```
static char ReadChar = 'a';
static bool ReadSuccess = false;

static void TryReading(object callback)
{
    int read = reader.Read();
    ReadChar = (char)read;
    ReadSuccess = true;
}
```

Basically... if the thread took too long to read the character - I aborted it and used the text it read so far.

This fixed the problem for me.